# 404 Not Found - Nginx - docker compose

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

It's a pretty standard docker container/setup

[image]

`index.php` is a standard call to `phpinfo();` only docker compose fails to serve this file in a browser?

[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl
#RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
#    PHP 7.4 ^^
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app_a:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app_a
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app_a
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver_a:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver_a
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8211:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db_a:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db_a
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3236:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_local
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

All the docker service containers are running fine and I'm able to log into them at the shell using `docker exec -it 3a234d1f384e sh` for example.

If you could assist me in serving the file in the browser?, that'd be great. Thanks in advance.

Edit

**/nginx/conf.d/app.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app_a:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're copying all the files to `/var/www`, but the standard directory for web servers is `/var/www/html`. Do you have a custom nginx configuration to serve files from `/var/www` ?

Comment: I have a custom nginx (`nginx/conf.d/app.conf`) config, yes. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my particular setup above. I think my mistake was `index.php` needs to be inside of a `public` folder and served from there.